# Add unobtrusive validation in asp.net on submit of page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to add validation in asp.net mvc. At the time of page load i have only a single text box for that validation works perfectly. but i want to add an another textbox at the run time which is also a required field in my database.

But i am not able to achive this. Html for the textboxes are same but the run time generated textbox is not showing required validation.

I am using code like this

Created a model as EmployeeVM

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

My view code is like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "kk" }))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            name
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.name)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dd"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
<input type="button" onclick="app()" value="add" />
```

And my javascript code is:

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function app() {
        $.removeData($("#kk"), 'validator');
        var tr = '<td>age:</td><td> @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.age)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.age) </td>';
        $("#dd").html(tr);

        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks and regards

Prince Chopra

Comment: @Tallmaris you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following line in the `<appSetting>` tag of your web.config file

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

You also have to make sure you're posting the form back to an actionmethod that checks if the modelstate is valid and if it is not then you return back to the view. Doing this will activate your validation messages.

Comment: yes its already in <appsettings>

`
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
`

Comment: I've added something extra to my answer for you to also check.

Comment: I found the solution. First i need to remove all the validation from the form and then need to call parse function

`
var form = $("#kk");
            form.removeData('validator');
            form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
`

@BenM